# Mention username in chatter message

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I need to post a chatter message with a specific user to the account when the account status field is as Activated. I have created a flow that sends a chatter message to an account, but can't specify the username. I can mention the record owner but not my name.

I want to post a chatter a message like this

@myusername Account is activated. Please add to the account directory.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add square brackets [ ] around the merge field, like this: [{!$Record.OwnerId}]

Add an @ symbol at the beginning and a comma at the end, like this: @[{!$Record.OwnerId}],

When followed by a value enclosed in square brackets, the @ symbol inserts the value as a mention in the Chatter post

Let me know if that helps!